# Issue faced in rest assured library

Tags: rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am working with rest assured libraries and building a automation utility for it. My target URL looks like `baseURL/catName,cat version`.

Now when I try to get response using rest assured, I am getting 404 error but same URL is working correctly in Postman/by putting directly is browser.

I think issue is with **","** present in my target URL, But I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: I would say that's because of space. Try to replace space with `%20`

Comment: There is no space in the URL

Comment: you have it in your question `catName,cat version` between `cat` and `version`.

Comment: By mistake I have written like this. Its baseURL/catname,catversion